# Magento Price Range Error: "1054 Unknown column 'e.min_price' in 'where clause'"

Tags: sql, magento

Folks, ground has skipped away.

I'm getting an error in one particular situation when using magento e-commerce (1.7.0.2). The situation is, when the user tries to filtrate the catalog product's by a price range. The error presented is this

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.min_price' in 'where clause'

Trace:
#0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/parcodesign-setembro/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/parcodesign-setembro/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/parcodesign-setembro/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/parcodesign-setembro/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT COUNT(DI...', Array)
#4 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/parcodesign-setembro/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT COUNT(DI...', Array)
#5 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/parcodesign-setembro/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(825): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#6 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/parcodesign-setembro/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(225): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchOne(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#7 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/parcodesign-setembro/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(225): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->getSize()
#8 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/parcodesign-setembro/app/code/community/Strategery/Infinitescroll2/Model/Catalog/Observer.php(40): Varien_Data_Collection->getLastPageNumber()
#9 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/parcodesign-setembro/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Strategery_Infinitescroll2_Model_Catalog_Observer->modifyCollection(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#10 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/parcodesign-setembro/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Strategery_Infinitescroll2_Model_Catalog_Observer), 'modifyCollectio...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#11 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/parcodesign-setembro/app/Mage.php(447): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('catalog_product...', Array)
#12 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/parcodesign-setembro/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Collection.php(506): Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_product...', Array)
#13 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/parcodesign-setembro/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(864): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection->_beforeLoad()
#14 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/parcodesign-setembro/app/code/core/Mage/Review/Model/Observer.php(78): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->load()
#15 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/parcodesign-setembro/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Mage_Review_Model_Observer->catalogBlockProductCollectionBeforeToHtml(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#16 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/parcodesign-setembro/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1311): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Review_Model_Observer), 'catalogBlockPro...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#17 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/parcodesign-setembro/app/Mage.php(447): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('catalog_block_p...', Array)
#18 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/parcodesign-setembro/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php(163): Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_block_p...', Array)
#19 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/parcodesign-setembro/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(862): Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List->_beforeToHtml()
#20 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/parcodesign-setembro/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#21 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/parcodesign-setembro/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('product_list', true)
#22 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/parcodesign-setembro/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Category/View.php(85): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('product_list')
#23 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/parcodesign-setembro/app/design/frontend/default/madame-modern/template/catalog/category/view.phtml(70): Mage_Catalog_Block_Category_View->getProductListHtml()
#24 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/parcodesign-setembro/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/Applications/X...')
#25 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/parcodesign-setembro/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
#26 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/parcodesign-setembro/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#27 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/parcodesign-setembro/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#28 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/parcodesign-setembro/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#29 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/parcodesign-setembro/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#30 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/parcodesign-setembro/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#31 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/parcodesign-setembro/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#32 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/parcodesign-setembro/app/design/frontend/default/madame-modern/template/page/2columns-left.phtml(19): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#33 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/parcodesign-setembro/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/Applications/X...')
#34 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/parcodesign-setembro/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
#35 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/parcodesign-setembro/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#36 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/parcodesign-setembro/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#37 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/parcodesign-setembro/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#38 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/parcodesign-setembro/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#39 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/parcodesign-setembro/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/CategoryController.php(159): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#40 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/parcodesign-setembro/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Catalog_CategoryController->viewAction()
#41 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/parcodesign-setembro/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#42 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/parcodesign-setembro/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#43 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/parcodesign-setembro/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#44 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/parcodesign-setembro/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#45 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/parcodesign-setembro/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#46 {main}
```

I've been tracing the problem around, with not much success. I'm not pretty sure if the problem is related to the missing table called "min_price" in database, or anything else. As you can notice, the characters exposed in the error report is "e.min_price", and not only "min_price". The only file which contains these characters is **app/code/core/Mage/CatalogIndex/Model/Indexer.php**

```
if (strlen($values[$code]['from'])>0) {
   $filter[$code]->where(
     "($table.min_price".implode('', $additionalCalculations[$code]).")*{$rateConversion} >= ?",
   $values[$code]['from']
   );
}

if (strlen($values[$code]['to'])>0) {
   $filter[$code]->where(
      "($table.min_price".implode('', $additionalCalculations[$code]).")*{$rateConversion} <= ?",
   $values[$code]['to']
   );
}
```

As you can see, actually it is "$table.min_price" and not "e.min_price". But this is the only file which contains these sequence of characters. ("min_price" appears in several others)

It, probably, has come to your attention that I`m pretty lost here. So, ANY help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`Strategery_Infinitescroll2` seems to be modifying the collection using an observer, it seems like they are trying to access a field that does not exist like you thought.

Check in `{community|local}/Strategery/Infinitescroll2/Model/Catalog/Observer.php` in the `modifyCollectio...()` method.

Disabled the module to confirm it is at fault, either fix it yourself shouldn't be too hard to remove / fix the check from the collection call.

or contact your supplier.

The stack trace line:

`#10 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/parcodesign-setembro/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Strategery_Infinitescroll2_Model_Catalog_Observer), 'modifyCollectio...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))`

Comment: Thanks for the answer,Input. I'll be checking for this as soon as possible.

Comment: unfortunately, disabling the module didn't helped at all. I also disabled some other recent added modules, just to check. But no success at all. Still trying to find the solution here. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was related to `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Price.php`
`apply()` method.

This file was not updated to the last version and the `apply()` method was still calling the deprecated method `$this->_getResource()->applyFilterToCollection($this, $range, $index);` instead of this `$this->_applyPriceRange();`

So I suggest to do a diff with an original core file at least for those 2 files:

- app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Price.php
- app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Layer/Filter/Price.php

**In case you have upgraded Magento:**
Take care could be ( probably ) more files that has not be updated correctly so I suggest to review the upgrade procedure.

Answer (score -1):

try to set flat product catalog to no in backend